# Laravel validator with Vuejs form validation error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm working with Laravel and vuejs for Signup process where have form validation for couple of fields, while password field filled with proper data then system raise an type error for vuejs, error is : TypeError: _vm.errors.password is undefined.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-default required" v-bind:class="[errors.password ? 'has-error' : '', '']" >
    <label>Password</label>                
    <input v-model="sign_up_details.password" class ="form-control validate instant-validate" placeholder="Password" type="password">
    <form-error v-if="errors.password" :errors="errors">
        {{ errors.password[0] }}
    </form-error>                
</div>
```

Comment: That's solved, one miss concept was there and that was : I've kept another password field which was hidden based on condition, so that system raised error.